# CSS Z-Index not affecting relatively positioned images

Tags: css

I have a CSS problem that I can't seem to overcome. I'm attempting to push the `img` from the `container` DIV upwards to overlap the `img` in the top DIV.

I've tried quite a few methods that don't work. Z-Index doesn't have any effect on the layering of the images, my understanding of Z-Index is far worse than I thought it was and some guidance would be really helpful.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- DIV CONTAINS THE HEADER IMAGE AND SOCIAL MEDIA PLUGINS 
     Padding: 0; Margin: 0; Border:0;                       -->

<div id="head-image" class="image">
    <!-- SOCIAL LINKS HERE -->
    <img src="images/mainImg.png" alt="" />
</div>

<!-- DIV CONTAINS ALL THE CONTENT ON THE PAGE
     padding:10px; Margin:0; Border:0;       -->

<div id="container">
    <div id="mapPlace">
        <img src="images/activityIcons/map.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <!-- TEXT DIV HERE -->
</div>
```

And my CSS rules

```
img {
    position:relative;
}

#head-image {
    position:relative;
    width:520px;
    height:482px;
    z-index:5;
}

#head-image img {
    z-index:5;
}

#mapPlace {
    position:absolute;
    top:-80px;
}

#mapPlace img {
    z-index:10;
}

#container {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:2%;
    width:96%;
    background-color:#000;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Please ignore the difference in naming conventions in the CSS. I am taking over someone elses code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine except that you have `overflow:hidden` on the container, which keeps the bottom image from ever getting up to the top image.

See this jsfiddle where I replace the images with div squares, and just removed the `overflow:hidden`:

http://jsfiddle.net/g72xV/

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's sorted it. Always amazed at how un-observant I can be sometimes!

Comment: Just FYI - I don't think you even need the z-indexes on the images if you already have them on their parents... I'm pretty sure z-index is inherited.